# Set new sprite position equal to last destroyed sprite position

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I'm currently making Asteroids with SMFL c++. The collision detection between the bullet and the asteroid is working. I want a new asteroid to be spawned in the place where the one that was just hit was. But the new asteroid keeps spawning where the original asteroids are supposed to spawn.
P.S (Don't really know how to do an MRE with this because you'd need all my code to reproduce it)

## Game.cpp

```
        // Create asteroids
        Asteroids asteroid(asteroid_width, asteroid_height);
        if (level_2 == false)
        {
            asteroid.spawnAsteroids(screen_width, screen_height, asteroid_width, asteroid_height);
        }
        else
        {
            max_asteroids++;
            asteroid.spawn_new(level_2);
            level_2 = false;
        }
        asteroid.chooseAsteroidDirection();
        asteroid.chooseTexture();

        // Push asteroids to asteroid vector
        if (asteroid_vector.size() < max_asteroids)
        {
            asteroid_vector.push_back(asteroid);
        }

        // Draw and move asteroids
        for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < asteroid_vector.size(); i++)
        {
            asteroid_vector[i].drawTo(window);
            asteroid_vector[i].moveAsteroids(dt);
            asteroid_vector[i].screenWrapping(screen_width, screen_height);
            asteroid_vector[i].collision(asteroid_dead, bullet_dead, asteroid_scale, bullet_vector, level_2);

            // If bullet_dead is true despawn the bullet
            if (bullet_dead)
            {
                bullet_vector.erase(bullet_vector.begin() + i);
                bullet_dead = false;
            }
```

## Asteroids.cpp

```
void Asteroids::spawnAsteroids(int screen_width, int screen_height, int asteroid_height, int asteroid_width)
{
    random_corner = rand() % 4;

    if (random_corner == 0)
    {
        spawn_point.x = asteroid_width;
        spawn_point.y = asteroid_height;
    }
    else if (random_corner == 1)
    {
        spawn_point.x = screen_width - asteroid_width;
        spawn_point.y = asteroid_height;
    }
    else if (random_corner == 2)
    {
        spawn_point.x = screen_width - asteroid_width;
        spawn_point.y = screen_height - asteroid_height;
    }
    else if (random_corner == 3)
    {
        spawn_point.x = asteroid_width;
        spawn_point.y = screen_height - asteroid_width;
    }

    asteroid.setTexture(asteroid_texture_1);
    asteroid.setPosition(spawn_point);
}

void Asteroids::collision(bool& asteroid_dead, bool& bullet_dead, float& asteroid_scale, std::vector<Bullet> bullet_vector, bool& level_2)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bullet_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        auto bullet = bullet_vector[i].bullet;

        // If current bullet collides with asteroid,
        // set asteroid_dead and bullet_dead to true
        if (bullet.getGlobalBounds().intersects(asteroid.getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            asteroid_dead = true;
            bullet_dead = true;
            asteroid.scale(asteroid_scale, asteroid_scale);
            level_2 = true;
        }
    }
}

void Asteroids::spawn_new(bool& level_2)
{
    if (level_2)
    {
        asteroid.setPosition(asteroid.getPosition().x, asteroid.getPosition().y);
    }
}
```

I want to set the new asteroids position to the same position as the one that just collided with the bullet. I tried doing this by plugging in the asteroid_vector[i]s position into the spawn_new function but it did the same thing.

Comment: You need to save the position and then use it for the next spawn. Can you point out where in your code you're doing that?

Comment: Do you have a class named `Asteroid`  too? Does it have a constructor taking a spawning position?

Comment: @TedLyngmo A different class thats not the ``` Asteroids ```  class ?

Comment: Yes, `Asteroids` sounds like it's the container for many `Asteroid` objects.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Technically it should be named asteroid. The class makes one asteroid but in the game loop pushed multiple of that asteroid to the asteroid_vector.

Comment: I see. Then `spawnAsteroids` and `spawn_new` should probably just be constructors.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want to do you need to save the position of the asteroid before it gets deleted. any data that you delete will be deleted without being able to get it back. Thus if you want to spawn something back in that position you need to save the position in for example an external vector of vectof2f positions of asteroids that were just deleted, after which you delete that position from the position vector.